# JavaScript array returns deepEqual

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to return an array

```
function estanParaTrasplantar(alturasDePlantas) {
  let plantasMayoresA20Cm = [];
  for (let planta of alturasDePlantas) {
    if (planta.altura > 20) {
      agregar(plantasMayoresA20Cm, planta);
    }
  }
  return plantasMayoresA20Cm;
}
```

When I run `[21, 29, 5, 20]` I get this output

```
[] deepEqual [ 21, 29 ]
```

How can I return the array without the deepEqual stuff? Thanks

Comment: si no hablas inglés, [existe este sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com) :) bueno suerte

Comment: What does `agregar` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using agregar, filter out numbers greater than 20

```
function estanParaTrasplantar(alturasDePlantas) {
  return alturasDePlantas.filter(x => x > 20)
}
```

**Note**

for of will pick some weird array prototype values hence the weird things you're getting.

Comment: It still returns [] deepEqual [ 21, 29 ]

Comment: @user16375788 see my edit,

Comment: Thank you but it keeps returning deepEqual

Comment: @user16375788 please check again

Comment: Yes. I tried it again, same result

Comment: what is the content of alturasDePlantas

Comment: @user16375788 check my code again, this time it should work and it's only one liner.

Comment: It's an array, [21, 29, 5, 20]. Already solved it, thanks for the help

Comment: You solved it in the most inefficient way possible.

Answer (score -1):

I edited Jorge's code and it worked. Thanks for all the help!

```
function estanParaTrasplantar(alturasDePlantas) {
  let plantas = alturasDePlantas;
  function maximo(lista){
    let mayores= [];
    lista.map(function(num){if (parseInt(num)>20){mayores.push(parseInt(num));}});
    return mayores;
  }
  return(maximo(plantas));
}
```

Comment: this is not how you should do it. You are violating immutability, declaring unnecessary variables, and casting integer to integer twice.